# How to Decoding AES-128 Data in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, security, openssl

I am exchanging data with a device that requires encryption. According to the instructions, my iOS app generates an RSA 2048-bit public-private key pair and I send the device the public key.

I created the public-private key pair using a macOS command line with `openssl` shown here (as I cannot figure out how to make iOS do it - but that's a future question):

`openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -out cert.pem`

`openssl x509 -in cert.pem -noout -pubkey`

I copied the values from the `cert.pem` and the private and public keys into my app:

`let certificate = "MIIDej....GWB"`

`let privateKey = "MIIFhz...Q=="`

`let publicKey = "MIIBI...AQAB"`

When I send the device the public key, the device is happy and sends back data in AES-128 encrypted using the public key I sent.

I am in over my head here, but I'm the one trying to get this device to work.

Is there a way to take the private key or cert that I have set as `String`s in my app to decode the data coming from the device?

I have been looking at the Security and CryptoKit docs and it makes my head swim.

FWIW, I was able to use `SecCertificateCreateWithData` on the String set from the `cert.pem` file and read some of its info like the summary. But I have no idea how to apply the private key or use the cert to decode the data. I need like a Dummies cliff notes or something.

Thank you.

Comment: "sends back data in AES-128 encrypted using the public key" is not possible. AES doesn't use public keys. It uses symmetric keys, which are completely different. There is no single standard way to implement what you're describing (there are several official standards, but many systems are ad hoc). The right way to handle this depends heavily on the exact protocol the server implements. Ideally you have a document describing that. If not, then the full server code. (Unfortunately, implementing ad hoc protocols often requires consulting rather than Stack Overflow questions.)

Comment: Thanks. I just pasted in what the documentation I was given stated. I will try to find the authors and work from there. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/certificate_key_and_trust_services/keys/generating_new_cryptographic_keys) describe how to generate key pair on the iOS side.

**Example:**

```
let tag = "com.example.keys.mykey".data(using: .utf8)!
let attributes: [String: Any] =
    [kSecAttrKeyType as String:            kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA,
     kSecAttrKeySizeInBits as String:      2048,
     kSecPrivateKeyAttrs as String:
        [kSecAttrIsPermanent as String:    true,
         kSecAttrApplicationTag as String: tag]
]

var publicKey: SecKey?
var privateKey: SecKey?
        
SecKeyGeneratePair(attributes, &publicKey, &privateKey)
```

More attributes are available [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/certificate_key_and_trust_services/keys/key_generation_attributes).

And then you can get External representations of private or public key using method:
[SecKeyCopyExternalRepresentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/1643698-seckeycopyexternalrepresentation).

**Example:**

```
var error: Unmanaged<CFError>?
SecKeyCopyExternalRepresentation(secKey, &error) as Data?
```

To decrypt AES-128 data you need to use `CCCrypt`. [Here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/52344?answerId=155801022#155801022) you have example from Apple support how the data is encrypted, but to decrypt data you need to change first argument to `kCCDecrypt`.

**Example:**

```
extern NSData * SecDecryptAES128CBCPad(NSData * data, NSData * key, NSData * iv) {
    CCCryptorStatus    err;
    NSMutableData *    result;
    size_t              resultLength;

    NSCParameterAssert(key.length == kCCKeySizeAES128);
    NSCParameterAssert(iv.length == kCCBlockSizeAES128);

    // Padding can expand the data, so we have to allocate space for that.  The rule for block
    // cyphers, like AES, is that the padding only adds space on encryption (on decryption it
    // can reduce space, obviously, but we don't need to account for that) and it will only add
    // at most one block size worth of space.

    result = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithLength:[data length] + kCCBlockSizeAES128];

    err = CCCrypt(
        kCCDecrypt,
        kCCAlgorithmAES128,
        kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
        key.bytes, key.length,
        iv.bytes,
        data.bytes, data.length,
        result.mutableBytes,  result.length,
        &resultLength
    );
    assert(err == kCCSuccess);

    // Set the output length to the value returned by CCCrypt.  This is necessary because
    // we have padding enabled, meaning that we might have allocated more space than we needed.

    [result setLength:resultLength];

    return result;
}
```

Arguments in `CCCrypt` method (like `kCCOptionPKCS7Padding`, `iv`) you need to adjust to your example.

Comment: Thanks for the decrypt hint. Generating the key pair does not work for this device. I am told I need PKCS8 and X509 keys. The public key generated by `SecKeyGeneratePair` is not recognized by the device which is why I resorted to finding a macOS solution via `openssl`. I have been reading the iOS is notoriously difficult to use with non-Apple services requiring encrypted data exchange. I will however, try to see if you solution works with the data returned by the device. Thank you.

Comment: @P.Ent But remember that using the private key as a plain string in your code is a security risk (when the app is available publicly) because it's easy to get it from binary using reverse engineering. For example, Hopper Disassembler is available for free and when the binary is loaded into this program all strings will be excluded from your code and will be visible.

Comment: I agree. Since I cannot figure out how to get iOS to generate the public key that's acceptable to this device, I put them as strings in the app just to move to the next step which is to encode/decode data from the device. But I have no idea what I'm doing but I am assigned to do this work. I would just like to know if I can use these plain strings. If not, I have no idea what to do except earn a degree in cryptography.

Comment: Yes because as it is described in docs of SecKeyCopyExternalRepresentation it returns `PKCS #1` format. So you need to find a solution to convert it to PKCS8. [Here](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5208.txt) you have rfc documentation how this format should looks like and also a [thread](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/85915) on the Apple Forum about that.